# Live activity is not updating when using background tasks

Tags: swift, widgetkit, activitykit

I am trying to implement a live activity in my application and update it every 5 minutes using BackgroundTasks. However, the live activity does not update neither in the background nor in the foreground.

The steps that I did to implement the background tasks is as follows:

1- Added a new capability in the main target (Background Mode) and selected background fetch and background processing.

2- Registered the background task in the app delegate inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "IDENTIFIER", using: nil) { task in
     LAManager.shared.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
}
```

3- Added the background task identifier in info.plist.

4- Implemented a method to schedule the task.

```
func scheduleAppRefresh() {
     let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "IDENTIFIER")

     // handle refresh based on the time added to now
     request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5 * 60)

     do {
         try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
     } catch {
         print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
     }
}
```

5 - Another method to handle the task (and schedule a new task).

```
func handleAppRefresh(task: BGProcessingTask) {
    scheduleAppRefresh()

    task.expirationHandler = {
       //DO Something after task expired
    }

    // do updates here
}
```

I am still not getting any updates to the live activity.

Comment: It's not possible to update Live activities when the app is in background, except with push notifications as shown in the documentation. If it doesn't work with your app in foreground it could be because nothing guaranty that your task will be run as soon as the time you asked (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskrequest/3142244-earliestbegindate).

Comment: @Morniak It is actually possible and it is also mentioned in their documentation that we can use Background Tasks to perform updates to the live activity in the background.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/activity/update(_:)

Comment: I am also working on this issue. I can confirm that updating a Live Activity (from 16.2 on, tested with iOS 16.4) is apparently not so easy. I have tried both BGAppRefreshTask as well as BGProcessingTask with an earliestBeginDate of 60 seconds into the future (I know it's a bit of a high frequency update) and only observed the actual update a few times and after many minutes. But it was generally unpredictable, in most test runs it did not happen within 10 minutes at all.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, it’s a hassle to update the live activity with BackgroundTasks. We eventually had to use remote push notification to update it and it’s working now.

Comment: @HashimAljawad Thanks! We found a small hack for a very specific case: If all you want to do is show the time since or until a certain Date, you can use Text(timerInterval: ...) to achieve that without updating the activity with background tasks nor push notifications. It didn't help us implement what we really wanted, but thought it would be good to share. If we pursue this further, we will try push notifications as well.